# Email Attachment From Lotusscript Agent

Tags: lotusscript

I have documents that get processed via a scheduled LotusScript agent. Each document has a $FILE field which is a jpg photo. In my agent, I want to take that photo on the document and email it to a specified address. Is this possible with a scheduled LotusScript agent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There are many approaches. One way is to make a copy of the NotesDocument object, delete all the NotesItems that you don't want in the email, leave the $FILE items alone, and add any NotesItems that you need for the email, then call NotesDocument.send(). This has the advantage of not having to save the attachment to disk and then reattach it to a new document for the email. This method has the potential disadvantage that the attachment in the document that you mail will not appear as part of the the emailed message Body the way a "normal" Notes attachment does. If you view that emailed message in the Notes client, the attachment icon will appear below a solid line across the bottom of the message, but it will still be fully functional.